# how to read the values of a multidimensional matrix stored in a file using loops

Tags: python

I am trying to read the values of a nxmxsx3 matrix, say amat, which are stored in a file. I try:

```
amat=np.zeros([n,m,s,3])

ifile=open("input.dat", "r")


for i in range(0, n - 1):
    for j in range(0, m - 1):
        for sind in range(0, s-1):
            amat[i,j,sind,0], amat[i,j,sind,1], amat[i,j,sind,2]= ifile.read().split()
```

but it returns the following error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Edit the question to show a short sample of the file as properly formatted text.

Comment: `ifile.read().split()` is a list of presumably `n*m*s*3` strings, which you are trying to put into just 3 places. Perhaps you want `readline()`? You should probably also do some conversion to `float`. I agree with @MichaelButscher that your question would be clearer if you gave some idea what your file looks like.

Answer (score 0):

turns out the answer is quite simple: one needs to correctly (using split) read each line (using readline)

```
amat[i,j,sind,0], amat[i,j,sind,1], amat[i,j,sind,2]= ifile.readline().split()
```